# Class-level validation

Tags: .net, wpf, data-annotations, validation

I am validating a class with [`DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) utils.

I have a class that has a `Title` property and an `Item` property.
I want to apply a [`RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) to the `Title` property but it should be invalid only if the `Item` property is null; if the `Item` property is set with an object, the `Title` is not required.

In short words, I want the [`RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) to validate only if a condition in the class is satisfied.

How can this be done.

### **Update**

As I didn't find other way, and since I usually don't need this functionality so often, I decided to make it the rough way using a class-level validator.
my question is then, is there a way to manually update the UI to make that Title TextBox with a red frame, i.e. to invalidate it?

**Update 2**
I want the class-level validator to summarize on a field.
For example, I have to fields Cost and SalesPrice, I wanna make sure that SalesPrice > Cost and invalidate the SalesPrice otherwise, I don't want a global validation  error on the class level.

I prefer to do it the xamly way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be able to do this by creating a custom validation attribute for the class. Unfortunately DataAnnotation attributes assigned to properties cannot access other properties of the parent class as far as I am aware hence the need to create a class validator.
Using the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace you will need to create you custom attribute class inheriting from ValidationAttribute and override the IsValid method (I have not tested the code below but it should get you going):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CustomAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
  public CustomAttribute()
  {
  }

  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
     if(value is myClass)
     {
       return ((myClass)value).Item != null &&
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(((myClass)value).Title) ? false : true;
     }
     else return true;
  }
}
```

Digging a little further it appears that whilst cross field validation it not possible out of the box it can be achieved by extending the framework to support it. See [this article for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/10/05/extending-asp-net-mvc-s-validation.aspx), hopefully this will be added to future versions of MVC.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, the problem is that it doesn't invalidate the Title field, I need to apply the ValidationAttribute on the Title property so the UI marks the Title TextBox as invalid with red frame and all the bs.

Comment: @Shimmy - see the link I have added for cross field validation. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: I decided to use the CustomValidationAttribute, it works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

well, on property level contingent validations are hard to achieve in MVC. but u can extend the framework or u can use some other library to achieve the goal. i m using foolproof validation by nick successfully for contingent validations in my project. u can take a look at it [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I am not using ASP.NET MVC, it's a WPF application but it doesn't matter. what matter is that I build a validation engine that invalidates a class by adding the property:error to a dictionary, and the UI invalidates according to what exists in this dictionary, now I want the validation error to be on property level (Title), not on class level. got it?