# How could i use DRY(don't repeat yourself) in DataAnnotations Error messages form Resourse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

here is my code

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals),ErrorMessageResourceName ="MustBeNumber")]
    [Display(Name = "BeneficiaryNo")]
    public long BeneficiaryNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-z]*$",ErrorMessage ="must only be letters")]
    [Display(Name = "FullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "GenderID")]
    public int GenderID { get; set; }`
```

Comment: You can write custom class-scope ValidationAttribute, which can accept in constructor, for instance, property names to be checked. Please, see code sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880727/class-level-validation)

Comment: if u see the simple code i posted  im using the errormessage resource type for the three,, how can i not repeat myself

Comment: I will show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept or DRY.

The fact you are repeating

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(DCC.RegistrationVMLiterals),ErrorMessageResourceName ="MustBeNumber")]
```

Isn't a Repeat in this context.

A repeat would be something like:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    string myString = "ABC";
    Print(myString);
    Do something...
}

public void DoSomething1()
{
    string myString = "ABC";
    Print(myString);
    Do something different...
}
```

The DRY response to this would be

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    Print(getString());
    Do something...
}

public void DoSomething1()
{
    Print(getString());
    Do something different...
}

public string getString()
{
    return "ABC";
}
```

Comment: Personally I think your code is fine. If you want to abstract the repetition of annotations your code will become a lot more complicated than it needs to be for no benefit in this instance.

Comment: @AndrewHarris, anyway this is kinda repetition problem, so if you have a huge domain model u can simplify work for yourself a little bit.

Comment: @Ryan I disagree. DRY is about addressing the issue where a repeated code block is updated in one place and not another (as one example). Each field here is and should be defined in its own right.

Comment: @AndrewHarris, entirely agree with you. Actually,  for current particular case my solution  looks like overengineering, more over in huge projects this is a matter of tradeoff: to apply attribute to a class, or just copy-paste the same code many times. But solution has right to live, so no point to argue.

Comment: In large projects where you want to reuse things like regex, apply logging to attribute and a few other things I would absolutely agree that you can do this, but for the most part its not addressing the problem DRY looks to prevent (exception being the repeating regex pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, have not tested, but this should work:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AggregatedRequiredAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _propertiesToValidate;
    private readonly string message = Resources.ValRequired;

    public AggregatedRequiredAttribute(params string[] propertiesToValidate)
    {
        if (propertiesToValidate == null || !propertiesToValidate.Any()) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertiesToValidate));
        _propertiesToValidate = propertiesToValidate;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!validationContext.ObjectType.GetMember(validationContext.MemberName).Any())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Current type does not contain such property.");

        if (!_propertiesToValidate.Contains(validationContext.MemberName))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        var defaultRequired = new RequiredAttribute() {ErrorMessage = message};
        return defaultRequired.IsValid(value) ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(message);
    }
}
```

Then u can use it like this (ViewModel from default MVC template):

```
[AggregatedRequired("Email","Password")]
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Notice, that i used error message string only once, also u can use some letter in error message and replace it dynamically to actual name of property being validated.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure about first `if` statement, you should test it.

**UPDATE 2**

Also i guess i used wrong `IsValid` method, but idea itself is clear.